# Internal Editor (pdf4eclipse) is not listed in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pdf, eclipse-plugin, latex

I am Trying to set up Eclipse with all its great features as my Latex editor by using TeXLipse. Everything seems to be working fine (tested with [SumatraPDF](http://teakes.blogspot.de/2009/08/setting-up-texlipse-and-sumatra-pdf.html)) but Pdf4Eclipse, which I totally want for the "update while writing" feeling.

What I figured out from asking Google till now is:
Pdf4Eclipse is not to be selected as Viewer in Texlipse, it is ought to be selected as the default viewer within Eclipse by klicking:

Window > Preferences: General > Editors > File Associations; select *.pdf and choose Pdf4Eclipse - but it is not there.

It is installed though, it has an entry in the preference settings. So the question is: Why is it not there, what did I do wrong )-:

Edit: Error log (please note my initial learning curve and the desperate spamming of install commands at the end):

```
!SESSION 2012-10-08 18:42:10.267 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800
java.version=1.7.0_07
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY net.sourceforge.texlipse 4 4 2012-10-08 18:44:59.172
!MESSAGE Could not start previewer 'itexmac'. Please make sure you have entered the correct path and filename in the viewer preferences.
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "" (in directory "C:\Users\Felix\workspace\test"): CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.texlipse.viewer.ViewerManager.execute(ViewerManager.java:555)
    at net.sourceforge.texlipse.viewer.ViewerManager.execute(ViewerManager.java:377)
    at net.sourceforge.texlipse.viewer.ViewerManager.preview(ViewerManager.java:133)
    at net.sourceforge.texlipse.viewer.TexLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(TexLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:855)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1047)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 11 more

!ENTRY net.sourceforge.texlipse 4 4 2012-10-08 18:48:07.453
!MESSAGE Could not start previewer 'itexmac'. Please make sure you have entered the correct path and filename in the viewer preferences.
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "" (in directory "C:\Users\Felix\workspace\test"): CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.texlipse.viewer.ViewerManager.execute(ViewerManager.java:555)
    at net.sourceforge.texlipse.viewer.ViewerManager.execute(ViewerManager.java:377)
    at net.sourceforge.texlipse.viewer.ViewerManager.preview(ViewerManager.java:133)
    at net.sourceforge.texlipse.viewer.TexLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(TexLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:855)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1047)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 11 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 4 0 2012-10-08 18:58:11.796
!MESSAGE Operation details
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 4 10050 2012-10-08 18:58:11.796
!MESSAGE Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 2 10005 2012-10-08 18:58:11.796
!MESSAGE "PDF4Eclipse" will be ignored because it is already installed.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 4 0 2012-10-08 18:58:11.799
!MESSAGE Operation details
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 4 10050 2012-10-08 18:58:11.799
!MESSAGE Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 2 10005 2012-10-08 18:58:11.799
!MESSAGE "PDF4Eclipse" will be ignored because it is already installed.'
```

**Edit 10.10.2012:**
I verified this behavior with another Eclipse Version 3.8 instead of 4.2 (both Platform runtime binary version) on Win XP (instead of Vista). No error log was generated during startup. Maybe I should file a bug report at github.org?

Comment: Have a look at your error log.  Any errors?  Paste them here.

Comment: does not fit in comment, one second please

Comment: Looks like this message may provide a clue: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "" (in directory "C:\Users\Felix\workspace\test"): CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden. (don't know Germain, so can't help further.)

Comment: Ah my bad, it means: "The OS cannot find the stated file"
Is there a way to see the 11 more entries of the error log? Or are they not meaningful and thus suppressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem (I guess the same. My problem was when I double-click a pdf file within texlipse, it is always opened in an external viewer, pdf-Xchange in my case), which was solved just now. Here is my solution and answer to your question:

In Window > Preferences: General > Editors > File Associations, for *.pdf, what appears in the "Associated editors" frame is "PDF Viewer (default)". This is in fact pdf4eclipse. You do not need to add anything. If you click "Add", you would not be able to add pdf4eclipse.

Then the problem in fact is that your texlipse already chose an external pdf viewer. Now go to Window > Texlipse > Viewer Settings, in "Viewer configurations", I guess you would see a pdf viewer. Just remove it, and now everything would be perfect. Double-clicking a pdf file in texlipse will open it in pdf4eclipse.

If you had the same problem as mine, then that's it.

Comment: In my case, this is not pdf4eclipse, but some weird other internal pdf viewer. At least it looks a lot different from what pdf4eclipse looked (a lot more basic) when I used it the last time. Also it was there already before I installed pdf4eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that there is a setting somewhere where you specify the full path to the itexmac program, but this setting is not filled in.

Have you gone through the steps at the end of this page?

http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/build.html

Comment: yes. as I said, thats the full error log of my session that day, I fixed that problem with ease.
Creating a new session (see also latest edit) does not throw any errors but pdf4eclipse still is not available. I can launch SumatraPDF or others as a viewer without problems.

Comment: This is starting to sound more like a texclipse problem.

Comment: I am not sure its TexLipse, as it should be listed as an editor in the eclipse internal editors; as stated in [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55798/pdf4eclipse-how-to-set-it-as-a-default-viewer) thread.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem and fixed it slightly differently than @unstable.

- In Window > Preferences: General > Editors > File Associations, search for "*.pdf" and in associated editors choose "add...".
- Choose "External programs", add Acrobat Catalog-index and hit ok.
- Choose Acrobat Catalog-index as default. Try to open your file with it. Then come back and make "PDF Viewer" as default.

That should solve the problem.